# pressing return in paragraph-indent-text-mode deletes whitespace indenting beginning of paragraph

Tags: indentation, major-mode, text-editing, whitespace

I'm currently using emacs 25.3 on Mac OSX installed using Homebrew, and without any modifications in my `.emacs` file or anywhere else. I think I may be fundamentally misunderstanding what `paragraph-indent-text-mode` is for. I enter `paragraph-indent-text-mode` using `M-x`. Then, I type four spaces (which from the documentation I'm assuming is supposed to indicate that I'm beginning a paragraph), then a few sentences that visually wraps around several times (with a `\` (backslash) character). Then, I use `RET` to begin a new paragraph.

Strangely, the whitespace at the beginning of the text that I just typed gets deleted automatically.

Now I repeat a few more times, and each time I use `RET`, the whitespace that I inserted previously gets deleted automatically, which I find to be *extremely* odd. I'm not putting any blank lines between paragraphs, because I'm assuming that's the entire point of `paragraph-indent-text-mode`: that you don't need to. However, because of this automatic deletion, all the text that I have typed now belongs to a single paragraph.

There must be something that I am completely missing here; how am I supposed to be using this mode to write paragraphs, if the very action that I'm supposed to be taking to indicate that I'm starting a new paragraph always gets deleted every time I use `RET`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much face-palming, head-desking, and head-walling, I finally discovered the issue.  paragraph-indent-text mode works PRECISELY as intended... or indented?  What's happening is that electric indent is stepping on its toes.  One way to fix it is to evaluate

```
(when (fboundp 'electric-indent-mode) (electric-indent-mode -1))
```

in your `.emacs` (init) file.

Comment: Sounds like a bug report is in order, then.

Comment: I just filed a bug report at bug-gnu-emacs@gnu.org